# Can I delete all data from the ACTIVEMQ_MSGS table?

Tags: activemq-classic

I have a live application that for some reason stopped processing messages.  Now after reboot there are 3 millions messages piled up.  Looks like it will take about 60 hours to process.  I'd like to just purge all of the messages.  How safe or dangerous is it to simply run a "DELETE FROM ACTIVEMQ_MSGS" type command to get rid of the messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not correct to delete something from a persistant storage directly. Try using API exposed via **JMX** instead.

Connect with **jconsole** or a similar tool to your broker management port (if not enabled - see the link below). Switch to the **MBean** tab, then: **org.apache.activemq** → **your_instance_name** → **Queue**. Afterwards, clean target queue(s) with "Purge" operation.

**JMX** must be enabled in the broker for use:
http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html